# CSS/HTML5 using :target or :active to display different text when link is clicked

Tags: html, css, target

Sorry as this may be a very open ended question... I am wondering if it is at all possible to display different text when a link is clicked. For example on my personal website if I was to have an "About" or "Contact" link could I switch the text of the body without reloading the page.

In the body of my index.html file I have:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="other"><a>About</a></li>
    <li id="other"><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li id="other"><a>Other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And in was wondering if I could using a:active or a:target in a separate CSS style sheet to perform the task as described above or if I need to use JS.

Comment: all those `li` can't have the same ID, thats invald HTML

Comment: This sounds like you would want to create a single-page application. Using just HTML and CSS for the purpose would be rather theoretical; web applications need a programming language, in practice JavaScript.

Comment: I don't know why I had those "other" IDs... I wasn't even using them (must have tried something then got rid of it without removing the IDs ) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of switching the text of the body without reloading the page is what is commonly known as “single page application”, a rather trendy thing with many benefits and some disadvantages or challenges. It is normally implemented using JavaScript, often using a library or framework, since that’s how we handle *programming* on web pages.

However, it is possible to achieve the very basic functionality of a single-page application using HTML and CSS only. This functionality means that the page has the content of an entire site and only a selected part of it is visible. You would use `:target`, which refers to the element that was the target of the most recent link that was followed. (The `:active` pseudo-class is something very different: it refers to a *link* or equivalent when it has been activated, typically by clicking on it, and before it has actually been followed – normally, a short time.)

Minimal example:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<style>
.section { display: none }
.section:target { display: block }
</style>
<div class="nav-bar">
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href=#About>About</a></li>
    <li><a href=#Contact>Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href=#Other>Other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id=About class=section>
About us
</div>
<div id=Contact class=section>
Contact us
</div>
<div id=Other class=section>
Other stuff
</div>
```

This does not work e.g. on IE 8 and older (which do not support `:target`), which is one of the reasons why this is a rather theoretical approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use Javascript to change things dynamically without page refresh ...  This is crude, but will show you how to do what you are expecting ...

**NOTE:** You must include the  `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` since I have used a bit of `jQuery` (A `JavaScript` library)

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-bar">
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="other1" onClick="changeText('other1');"><a>About</a></li>
    <li id="other2" onClick="changeText('other2');"><a>Contact</a></li>
    <li id="other3" onClick="changeText('other3');"><a>Other</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="page_content">
PAGE CONTENT!!
</div>

<script>
 function changeText(text){
      if (text === 'other1'){
      $('#page_content').html('About Us!!');
      }
      if (text === 'other2'){
      $('#page_content').html('Contact Us!!');
      }
      if (text === 'other3'){
      $('#page_content').html('Other!!');
      }

 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to implement the answer above as I understand it better (my JS is not very good) but I will have to use this later on if I would like users with IE 8 or older to be able to view my page.